# Meaning of "varying"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> Birds with the wrong types of beak would have gradually died out. On
>   an island with different conditions a slightly different sort of finch
>   would evolve. Over long periods of time the birds’ beaks became better
>   and better adapted to their environment. The **varying** environments on
>   different islands meant that the birds that thrived were the ones best
>   suited to that place.

What does the word "varying" mean? 
I think it has the same meaning with "different", is it right?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it basically means different.  If it were used as a verb, we could say,

"The weather on this island varies considerably from time to time.  Sometimes it is really hot and then all of a sudden it can start snowing out of the blue."